# Amazon Alexa app prohibits disabling of Amazon sidewalk

Tags: amazon-appstore

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GZ4VSNFMBDHLRJUK

gives instructions on how to disable Amazon sidewalk from within the Alexa app. But on my phone following those instructions does not show the selection.

My phone is a stock Samsung Galaxy Note 10 Lite:

Model name  Galaxy Note10 Lite
Model number  SM-N770F/DS
One UI version
3.1
Android version
11
Google Play system update
May 1, 2021
Baseband version
N770FXXU7EUC6
Kernel version
4.9.191-21082235
#1 Fri Mar 26 21:29:05 +07 2021
Build number
RP1A.200720.012.N770FXXU7EUC6
SE for Android status
Enforcing
SEPF_SM-N770F_11_0008
Fri Mar 26 21:42:21 2021
Knox version
Knox 3.7
Knox API level 33
TIMA 4.1.0
Service provider software version
SAOMC_SM-N770F_OLM_XXV_RR_0007
XXV/XXV,XXV/XXV

See the screenshot below showing that the entry does not exist.

Is this a defect in the Amazon Alexa app, or a defect in my phone?

[image]